# how to solve css file issue

Tags: html, css

I just tried to open my website some few minutes ago and I found out that the styling is all wrong, I set out to investigate what's wrong and I found something new to me. Two of my Css file appear corrupt with gibberish, I don't understand why. Although I replaced them with fresh copies, but I want to know why it is corrupt in the first place and how to advert it.

Here is the content of the CSS File;

`.span3 {
    width: 270px;
  }
  .span2 {
    width: 170px;
  }
  .span1 {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .offset12 {
    margin-left: 1230px;
  }
  .offset11 {
    mˆ��g�Ç¯éŸtU.�/¼òŸtU.�E��HTTP/1.1 200 OK�status:200 OK�version:HTTP/1.1�alternate-protocol:443:quic�cache-control:private, max-age=1800�content-encoding:gzip�content-type:application/javascript; charset=utf-8�date:Sat, 12 Apr 2014 19:31:27 GMT�etag:"3d991965deadc1b9dc22d74fc02fe42d"�expires:Sat, 12 Apr 2014 19:31:27 GMT�p3p:CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."�server:GSE�timing-allow-origin:*�x-content-type-options:nosniff�x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN�x-ua-compatible:IE=edge, chrome=1�x-xss-protection:1; mode=block��������…��0‚0‚i Fzí{"ü±0
   *†H†÷
�0I10  UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G20
140402153545Z
140701000000Z0f10  UUS10U
California10U
Mountain View10U

Google Inc10U*.google.com0Y0*†HÎ=*†HÎ=B�ó™•6D”¯ËOJý�¹.b:…úgQ´)ËKE�”ð×VQ«qlda˜œ¶êáÃkê’°Rk[ŸãÕ§{td   Œ”£‚0‚0U%0++0‚âU‚Ù0‚Õ‚*.google.com‚
*.android.com‚*.appengine.google.com‚*.cloud.google.com‚*.google-analytics.com‚*.google.ca‚*.google.cl‚*.google.co.in‚*.google.co.jp‚*.google.co.uk‚*.google.com.ar‚*.google.com.au‚*.google.com.br‚*.google.com.co‚*.google.com.mx‚*.google.com.tr‚*.google.com.vn‚*.google.de‚*.google.es‚*.google.fr‚*.google.hu‚*.google.it‚*.google.nl‚*.google.pl‚*.google.pt‚*.googleapis.cn‚*.googlecommerce.com‚*.googlevideo.com‚
*.gstatic.com‚
*.gvt1.com‚*.urchin.com‚*.url.google.com‚*.youtube-nocookie.com‚
*.youtube.com‚*.youtubeeducation.com‚*.ytimg.com‚android.com‚g.co‚goo.gl‚google-analytics.com‚
google.com‚googlecommerce.com‚
urchin.com‚youtu.be‚youtube.com‚youtubeeducation.com0U€0h+\0Z0++0†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0++0†http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0U48¦£º¯›[kø7¿ÖÂõ×û0Uÿ0�0U#0€JÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0U 00
+Öy00U)0'0% # !†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
   *†H†÷
�‚�€r»üH5M/·—°%ì©ôw˜ØG»FC$ç`Ô`Š
Zv7Ð!TteáU  $]Ê°T}ûŒ;wQý‚ÀUG»UØûTÅ½Žk¥óäÙ¦}ÃßpËÉiƒ÷óhïxŸ\`â9ç\ôV½(ïn#B'¬Ïxôq:‡»hßQ¡ÄÌÐßaéÚ¡*b) PU®mîƒïñHÃÏÿBSfF)YL·`Ûbd²-êÌZ?X
}8ï³)ô}…€û/ºås™B°ÍÏ
ƒëk$i'Ëqdô ¯-;°/®AŽßÉM!5ß¡˜ßI³§Š¦î1X3KÁÕ½3Eg÷Coí¢ÌßøR�����0‚0‚ì :i0
   *†H†÷
�0B10  UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0
130405151555Z
150404151555Z0I10  UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G20‚"0
   *†H†÷
�‚�0‚
‚�œ*w\ØP‘:£‚àØPH¼‰?ñpˆF~àÅñ‰Î!îZþa
·2D‰ tSOU¤Î‚b•îëY_Æá€Ä^”?¼[H8ôS÷$æû‘éÄÏôS
ôJüŸTÞ}¾ ko‡ÀÐP(0@ÚsQlÿ:<§7Ž½Kë}$Þæùü1qû”Õ`ó.J¯BÒËêÄj²ÌSÝK‹ÈaÍ¨>c+„5ie„ÈÅF"øS•¾ã€JÆ*ìº— Ç9™ ðaz•%ŒNRuâ¶íÊüÎ"j³NÏF——~À±Þ{¯E3Ïº>q·Þô%%Â
5‰ûy‰7Å¯Žri�£û0ø0U#0€Àz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0UJÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0Uÿ0ÿ�0Uÿ0:U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/gtglobal.crl0=+10/0-+0†!http://gtglobal-ocsp.geotrust.com0U 00
+Öy0
   *†H†÷
�‚�6×€'­*›8w³# uX»±~ƒBºrÚØŽ6—àð•;7ýBXþ"Èk½8^Ñ;%në^gvF@ÚÈx
í•fÚŽ†o€¡ºV2•†ÜÜjÊŒ[ö¿Ìo…XÃhQÍýÈ÷y=™5ðV£½àYíOD  £ž8zöFÑO¾Ð@üUþ^<ÚV½–Q{oW*Û¢ª–ÜŒtÂ•¾ðn•ÿð<¬²ÌsûèÆðû3³•;ãÂËhXsÛ¨$b;5
©3½x.Lx]P:Ôî Èp8Ü²ùgú‡@]aÀQkƒkÍ:Êá§xüÊÚ”Ð,=~yÈ P $T3qX��0‚T0‚< 4V0
   *†H†÷
�0B10  UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0
020521040000Z
220521040000Z0B10  UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0‚"0
   *†H†÷
�‚�0‚
‚�ÚÌc0ýô#V~[ßÇŠRÛ´½m›åÆ±Th©ãi¶š¥¸¹? }®Jµ¸œä¶«æ”¥ÁÇƒ­Ûõ'‡lÕÿÝ ]í‡R·+®9¦jtéÚÄç¼M4©\M3_’  /ˆf]w—Çv©Õåñ 5Õ¬Û$qp,˜VÙ´ÑãQ+^uèÕÐÜO4íÂf€¡Ëæ3����€���    À@����173.194.69.100��»�����spdy/3.1radius: 3px;`

Comment: Looks like google's ssl cert bled into your css file. You know, usual stuff o_O

Comment: usual? If this is usual then I think is wrong in every aspect cause it caused problem for the website and I will have to always check out for this?

Comment: This is a programming question suitable for SO because...?

Comment: @BlackPearl, sorry it was a lighthearted comment - because it's far from usual. I'd verify that the file on your local machine where you uploaded from is still intact, and if so, then there's something going wrong on the webserver.

Comment: @john3136 And you think it is not? If it is not, then it is what?

Comment: @BlackPearl OS? Hosting? What are you thinking you'll program to stop it happening again? I'm sure it's not a bug in your app that caused it to happen in the first place!

Comment: @flauntster I have solved the issue by replacing the file at the server with the one from my local machine and it has returned to normal. I have not come across this, I tried googling it but to no avail (maybe I kinda missed the keywords). What is weird here is that it saved stuff in bootsrap-responsive.min.css and another file, thereby rendering them useless.

Comment: @John3136 Hosting is on Linux Server. Yea, that is what I want to be rest assured about. I want to be rest assured that this is not a kinda bug or an attempt to hack the site.

Comment: @BlackPearl I will offer you a solution (not a great one) - I once had a site that was using an insecure CMS where "something" would inject bogus frames into index.php  roughly once a week. I set up a cron job to copy the good files back over "hacked" ones when it detected they had been changed - might work for you if you are paranoid about this happening again.

Comment: @John3136 for now, I will stick to this (always check and replace bad files) but I will still want to know the source of the problem. Since I don't have anything regarding google authentication on the website, I kinda think it is a problem from my host or something. I just remembered that I have this `google verification html file` in the website, is it possible that the problem is from this file?

Comment: I had the same issue but with a js-file. I uploaded it again as you did and that solved it. It would be interesting knowing why this happened..